# Multiple Ignite instance in tomcat application

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, tomcat8, ignite

We use Ignite to manage some caches, http session clustering... in a java web application using spring in a tomcat8 server.
So it seems to start 2 ignite instances one which start with spring :

```
 <beans:bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCacheManager">
    <beans:property name="igniteInstanceName" value="hibernate-grid"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And another that don't join the cluster because there is no configuration for it and its name is CacheManager_0.

I have in catalina.out logs

> org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Performance suggestions for grid '**CacheManager_0**' (fix if possible)

And in application logs

> INFO  o.a.i.i.IgniteKernal%hibernate-grid:117 -   IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=**hibernate-grid**,...

So I imagine that tomcat8 launch ignite grid with no configuration. Is there any way to avoid that ?

[image]

Comment: could you please share full log, which you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I read more log so I see javamelody (monitoring project https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody). So I rename my own grid to CacheManager_0 and I go to the monitoring page and get that error :

```
Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Ignite instance with this name has already been started: CacheManager_0
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1266)
at org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:127)
at org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider.getCacheManager(CachingProvider.java:111)
at org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider.getCacheManager(CachingProvider.java:157)
at org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider.getCacheManager(CachingProvider.java:162)
at net.bull.javamelody.internal.model.JCacheInformations.buildJCacheInformationsList(JCacheInformations.java:95)
at net.bull.javamelody.internal.model.JavaInformations.<init>(JavaInformations.java:204)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314460/is-there-any-hack-to-disable-ignite-hazelcast-from-launching-when-javamelody-i